# How to access the file system in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a file storage app that needs to read the contents of the sd-storage and internal phone storage.
I've checked out react-native-fs and react-native-fetch-blob but both of these apps only allow me to access my app's storage.
How can I read the other files present on the phone?

Comment: Have you found a solution for it ? I need to do the exact same thing on React native iOS

Comment: Yes I did actually. By using react-native-fs which was recommended to me in the answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe react-native-fs does support external storage in Android.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs#constants):

> `ExternalDirectoryPath` (`String`) The absolute path to the external files, shared directory (android only)
>
> `ExternalStorageDirectoryPath` (`String`) The absolute path to the external storage, shared directory (android only)

Comment: Yes that's true actually.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bkk if this is the answer you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: Have you had any success with this on Android 10? I worked in Android 8 but can no longer see the USB drive's path in Android 10.

Comment: can i access to folder download? just open or show folder download

Answer (score 0):

it does access the external storage you just need to ask for permission for external storage