# How to access an image file using FFmpeg in a React Native (Android) / Expo project?

Tags: android, react-native, ffmpeg

I made an app where I want to create a video from a png using FFmpeg in React Native but I'm stuck at my image file path part. FFmpeg uses the file system of the android so I can't really use paths like `./assets/img.png`. I need an absolute path - can't use `require('img.png')`

Here is my FFmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.png -t 10 -r 1 -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

How can I reach the `res` or `assets` folder on an android? Is there a way to bundle it into my app so on my android I can access it through an absolute path somehow?

I searched a lot of questions similar to this and most of the answers are the use of `require('img.png')` but this doesn't work for me because the way `FFmpeg` works. Is there a way to access my image file with `FFmpeg` in a React Native Android project?

Comment: Most players don't like MP4 with frame rate lower than 6 or so. If you still want 1 fps output use `ffmpeg -framerate 1 -loop 1 -i img.png -t 10 -c:v libx264 output.mp4`. It will be faster because you won't be performing a 25 fps (default image input fps) to 1 fps conversion. Secondly, add `-vf format=yuv420p` output option if you want the video to be playable by non-FFmpeg based players.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Found a more simpler solution for people using Expo or Expo ejected project:

```
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';

const content = await Asset.loadAsync(require('../../assets/img.jpg'));
const localUri = content[0].localUri;
```

This will give you your localUri for your image from the project Assets folder! You will have to install `Expo Asset` for this to work and import it just like any other library.

**Solution 2**

For people that would like to get the file from their local assets folder and not from a web uri here is the solution I found using the `Expo File System` library:

```
const imgUri = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}/bg_img.jpg`;
await FileSystem.copyAsync({from: 'asset://assets/images/bg_img.jpg', to: imgUri });
```

I also created an asset image folder under: `/android/app/src/main/assets/images` and added my `.jpg` file there.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access images in `res` or `assets` folders from `ffmpeg` command line: they are not 'files' in the file system, they are bundled in the APK (or one of the APK files, if your app is distributed as an Android Bundle). You should copy the images to a temporary location, probably [on the external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42394997/192373) that the system allocates to your app. You don't need extra permissions to write these files. The name of this directory is not fixed, so you will need to build the **ffmpeg** command line dynamically. [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) provides all the necessary functions.